# How get access to database into wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

All plugins works, but in my custom plugin $wpdb, wp_create_user, wp_insert_user doesn't works. 
For example, doesn't work

```
$user_id = 1;
$website = 'http://wordpress.org';
wp_insert_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'user_url' => $website) ) ; 


global $wpdb;
if(!isset($wpdb)) {
     require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
     //require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
     require_once('../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}
   $insertUser = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->users (user_login, user_pass, user_email, user_url) VALUES ('123', '123',     'rokk@gmail.com', 'lasad.com')";
    $wpdb->query( $insertUser );
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: And please provide your error messages

Comment: In addition to @SLaks comment, escape the password and hash it.

Comment: This is only part of the problem. How you explain this $user_id = 1;
$website = 'http://wordpress.org';
wp_insert_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'user_url' => $website) ) ;

Comment: @Charles this is test value. If I hash password problem will not be solved.

Comment: @Charles: No.  Hashing does not require escaping.

Comment: @SLaks Depends. If you do something like this: `"INSERT INTO (column) VALUES (md5('".mysql_real_escape_string($string)."'))"` it certainly does.

Comment: @Charles: MD5 should not be used.  AFAIK, MySQL does not have any hash methods that should be used for passwords.

Comment: @SLaks Why should md5 not be used? It is a hash method in mysql, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @SLaks What would you use instead?

Comment: @Charles: For passwords, bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDFv2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference to the user table is incorrect.

Under your declaration of global $wpdb;
try this

```
$wpdb->wp_users = 'wp_users'
```

and then in your sql,

instead of using the reference $wpdb->users in your query, use:

```
$wpdb->wp_users
```

you can use this for any wordpress table, just make sure you are naming your table correctly, double check the table names in phpmyadmin

But for your case Id avoid doing this insert and use the wordpress function
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user
Try out the example there.  It contains essential checks that you need to do before entering a new user, such as if they already exist/duplicate user names.  And will automatically set things like the User_Id number, and randomize your password so it isnt shown in plain text.

Comment: I try this, but no results... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user example also doesn't work. I think problem in access into database...

Comment: hmmm you probably aren't loading the the load and config files correctly.  Try adding something like this at the top of your page before you actually call the function, you might have to adjust the root directory in this code depending on where your file is. $root = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
if (file_exists($root.'/wp-load.php')) {
require_once($root.'/wp-load.php');
} else {
require_once($root.'/wp-config.php');
}